# How does keras choose the input from its shape

Tags: tensorflow, input, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In Keras, we don't specify what the input is, we rather specify its shape. How does Keras  choose what array to use as an input?

For example, I have two models that have different input, but the two inputs have the same shape. How can I specify which input goes to which model?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you talking about defining the model inputs and outputs or about feeding actual values to the net for training and testing?

Comment: I am sorry I a bit new to this stuff. Lets say I have two models model_1 and model_2 that are fit using model.fit (x=[input_1,input,_2]).If I am using API function how can precise which input to which model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models in Keras/Tensorflow are first "designed", only when they are ready you feed them with data.

The model receives the data when you call any of these:

```
model.fit()
model.fit_generator()
model.train_on_batch()

model.predict()
model.predict_generator()
```

Comment: I am sorry I a bit new to this stuff. Lets say I have two models model_1 and model_2 that are fit using model.fit (x=[input_1,input,_2]).If I am using API function how can precise which input to which model?

Comment: `model` is the name of the var for one model.

Comment: I am merging the model_1 and model_2 into model and then I am compiling and fitting model using inputs x[x=[input_1,input,_2]

Comment: The same order you used when merging.